# Redirecting stdout, don't understand behavior

Tags: c, io, dup2

I've been trying to get a simple i/o redirect working using dup2. I've followed exactly the code that other people say works, but still no success.

```
int out = open("stdoutput", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
printf("STANDARD OUT\n");
dup2(out, 1);
printf("SEND TO FILE\n");
dup2(1, out);
close(out);
printf("BACK TO STANDARD OUT\n");
```

This prints STANDARD OUT to the terminal and 
SEND TO FILE
BACK TO STANDARD OUT
to the file. Why doesn't it switch back?

I also want to have a fork/exec output stdout to a file.

```
int out2 = open("execout", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
printf("STANDARD OUT\n");
dup2(out2, 1);
if(fork() == 0)
{
    execvp("time", NULL);
    perror(NULL);
}

dup2(out2, 1);
close(out2);
printf("BACK TO STANDARD OUT\n");
```

This prints to the terminal:

STANDARD OUT
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal: No such file or directory
        0.00 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys

and to the file execout, it prints:
BACK TO STANDARD OUT

There seems to be some additional issue with the exec call to time (not finding it but then printing it anyway?) but my main issue is with the I/O redirects not working right.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Update: There seems to be a problem specifically with exec not sending output to file. The code:

```
int output_file = open("gcc_output", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

if(fork() == 0)
{
    dup2(output_file, 1);
    close(output_file);
    char *args[] = {"gcc", path, NULL};
    printf("THIS GOES TO FILE");
    execvp(args[0], args); // gcc output, errors etc. go to terminal
    perror("exec");
    exit(2);
}
```

Does exec cause it to lose it's file descriptors or something?

Comment: It doesn't switch back because `out` and `1` are the same after the first `dup2` call, so the second `dup2` call does nothing.

Comment: And it would be worth checking the results of your `dup2` calls to confirm that.

Comment: when calling the system functions: `dup2()` and `open()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: *Does exec cause it to lose it's file descriptors or something?*  No, but the command you spawn might figure out how to send its output to the terminal anyway. Run your executable under `strace -f -o /path/to/output/file /path/to/your/executable ...` to see what system calls the `exec()`'d process makes.  (And calling `exit()` after a failed `fork()` can cause all kinds of issues - the child's copy of the *parent's* exit handlers get called, and data in the child's copy of the *parent's* IO buffers gets flushed to the files the *parent* had open at the time of `fork()`. Use `_exit()` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

`dup2(from, to)` copies the file descriptor `from` to the file descriptor `to`; if `to` was open, it is silently closed before being overwritten.

In your first example, you open the file `stdoutput` for writing; it is given the lowest possible descriptor number (probably 3); then your `dup2(out2, 1)` copies this descriptor over the standard output descriptor 1; the original standard output is silently closed. There are now 4 open descriptors:

- 0 is the original standard input
- 1 is opened for writing to file `stdoutput`
- 2 is the original standard output
- 3 is opened for writing to file `stdoutput`

Finally you try to "restore" the original standard output by copying a file descriptor 1 over the file descriptor 3.

Instead, you should've stored the *original* standard output to another file descriptor by `dup`:

```
int out = open("stdoutput", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
printf("STANDARD OUT\n");
int saved_stdout = dup(1); // create a copy of the stdout file descriptor
dup2(out, 1);
close(out);                // close the extra descriptor
printf("SEND TO FILE\n");
dup2(saved_stdout, 1);     // copy the saved stdout file descriptor to 1
close(saved_stdout);       // close the copy of stdout
printf("BACK TO STANDARD OUT\n");
```

---

Your `execvp` call is broken too; there should be additional argument that is the command name; also `time` does not print the current date, but is a command that expects another command as an argument - perhaps you wanted to execute the `date` command instead? Additionally, you'd want to do the `dup2` **only** in the child process after the fork! Try the following:

```
int out2 = open("execout", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
printf("STANDARD OUT\n");
if (fork() == 0) {
    dup2(out2, 1);
    close(out2);
    execvp("date", "date", (char *)NULL);
    perror("exec");
    exit(2);
}
close(out2);
printf("STILL POINTING TO STANDARD OUT\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Still having trouble with exec (updated my question).